# Javascript ES6 import with @ character

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have folder in node_modules named: @mymodule and inside it there is a folder named 'insidefolder'

Path looks like this: **node_modules/@mymodule/insidefolder**

Using ES6 syntax I try to import insidefolder in this module:

```
import insidefolder from '@mymodule/insidefolder';
```

I get an error: `Error: Cannot find module '../ymodule/insidefolder'`

```
const mymodule = require('@mymodule/insidefolder');
```

Works just fine.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried adding an alias to it in your webpack config? You could add some alias like “mymodule”: “@mymodule/inside”, I haven’t tried as I haven’t had your case, but might work

Comment: Oh, in case you’re using webpack of course... my bad for not asking

Comment: @JavisPerez Haven't tried adding alias. I have a lot of different paths nesting in mymodule so would need a lot of aliases.

Comment: Could you possibly escape the @ symbol? It seems the import statement takes the combination of '@m' as a special character.

Comment: Well, you could try aliasing the whole folder like “mymodule”: “@mymodule” and just do ‘mymodule/inside’

Comment: @NikolaGeneshki I don't know how to quite do it. Tried '\@'. Doesn't work.

Comment: @Elminday Well, I'm out then...

Comment: @JavisPerez What is the difference between .babelrc alias and webpack.config alias?

Comment: I haven’t really used .babelrc aliases (didn’t know it existed) but webpack is the bundler, so it’s the responsible for resolving the paths to import, while Babel is just to polyfill es6 syntax

Comment: @JavisPerez I am using Rfx stack. https://github.com/foxhound87/rfx-stack
I don't really understand which file is the true config of webpack in the source where I need to defined alias.

Comment: Ok, so, for what I see, looks like they have splitted the webpack config into multiple files, in your place i would try with the `webpack/config.client.js` or `webpack/config.server.js` (not really sure which one is the responsible for the dependencies you're attempting). Just in case, here's an example for the webpack alias: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/ I really hope this help, it should be easy to add

Answer (score 2):

It happens so that my .babelrc had plugin:

```
["babel-root-import", [{
      "rootPathPrefix": "@",
      "rootPathSuffix": "src"
    }]]
```

And every import starting with @ pointed to src path. I deleted this and everything works just fine.